# identify unique letters and corresponding count in input_string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

```
input_string=mississippi

output_dict={letters=[i,s,p,m],count=[4,4,2,1]}
```

Remove duplicate entries from `input_string` and count those duplicate values and display in descending order.
actual following code remove duplicate entry but how to count the duplicate values

```
def mock(input_string):
    a=list(input_string)
    list1=[]
    for i in a:
        if i not in list1:
            list1.append(i)


    print(list1)           


mock("radffffghhh")
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh how can i do without counter

Comment: Have a look at the sections about `list` and `str` in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), and see what methods are available for these types. There are other ways to solve your problem, but both of these types have a `count` method. Note also that strings are iterable, just like lists, so you don't have to make a list out of your string, just use it the same way directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d={}
for i in input_string:
    d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1
```

sort dict by values in reverse

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1],reverse=True)#[('i', 4), ('s', 4), ('p', 2), ('m', 1)]
```

Using groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
{k:len(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(sorted(input_string))}
```

Using Counter

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(input_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit to do this without Counter:

```
def char_counter(string):
    count = {}
    for s in string:
        if s in count:
            count[s] += 1
        else:
            count[s] = 1
    return count         


char_counter(input_string)
```

output for "mississippi":

```
>>> char_counter(input_string)
{'i': 4, 'm': 1, 'p': 2, 's': 4}
```

collections has a package for this mentioned above called Counter. So taking your string:

```
from collections import Counter

input_string='mississippi'

Counter(input_string) # call Counter on your input string

#alternative to just call counter on the string:
Counter('mississippi')
```

output for both:

```
>>> Counter(input_string)
Counter({'i': 4, 'm': 1, 'p': 2, 's': 4})
>>> Counter('mississippi')
Counter({'i': 4, 'm': 1, 'p': 2, 's': 4})
```

Comment: has_key is not present in dictionary(it is present in earlier version of python)

Comment: Sorry I fixed it for python3.x

Comment: if i need to sort {'i': 4, 'm': 1, 'p': 2, 's': 4} in descending order then how can i do that. output should be {"i":4,"s":4,"p":2,"m":1}