# sort value in dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

if input is={"i":4,"m":1,"s":4,"p":2}
output should be={"i":4,"s":4,"p":2,"m":1}
how i sort values in dictionary in descending order

print(sorted(dict,reverse=True)).I have used this but not getting results

Comment: I have already provided an answer and you have accepted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542867/identify-unique-letters-and-corresponding-count-in-input-string/52544046#52544046

Answer (score 1):

I cant test this code right now, but it should be fairly close

```
# get sorted entries
s = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
# since Python 3.6, dictionaries are sorted by entry
# if you're using an older Python, check out collections.OrderedDict
d = {k: v for (k,v) in s}
```